# Collapse character vector into single observation in R

Tags: r, text, vector

How do you reduce a multi-valued vector to a single observation? Specifically, dealing with text. The solution should be scalable.

Consider:

```
col <- c("This is row 1", "AND THIS IS ROW 2", "Wow, and this is row 3!")
```

Which returns the following:

```
> col
[1] "This is row 1"           "AND THIS IS ROW 2"       "Wow, and this is row 3!"
```

Where the desired solution looks like this:

```
> col
[1] "This is row 1 AND THIS IS ROW 2 Wow, and this is row 3!"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for `?paste`:

```
> paste(col, collapse = " ")
#[1] "This is row 1 AND THIS IS ROW 2 Wow, and this is row 3!"
```

In this case you want to collapse the strings together and add a space in between them. You can also check out `paste0`.

Comment: awesome, thanks. will accept once the timer allows me.